# how to delete items from to do list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to duplicate code from CodeCademy on building a todo list, specifically, DELETING items...
adding items works fine, deleting items does nothing (although it works fine in the CodeCademy test window). It's the exact same code copied from  CodeCademy.

Thanks in advance!

**CODE:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button').click(function() {
     var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
     $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
     $(this).remove();
   });
 });
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.list {
  font-family: garamond;
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>To Do</h2>
<form name="checkListForm">
  <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your consol?

Comment: Works for me [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls8wgz5c/11/)